# how to display the mongoose result in html page or jade page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.get('/', function(req , res){

db.users.find({name:"raju",lastname:"david"},function(err,docs){if(docs) {console.log(docs.name);}});

res.sendfile(__dirname + '/mongo.html');
});
```

please help me how to display the mongoose result of name and the last name to the html page or jade template as a front end .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use render, not sendfile

```
 app.get('/', function(req , res){
  db.users.find({name:"raju",lastname:"david"}, function(err,docs){
     res.render('mongo',{data:docs});     
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

Please ensure you have directory view configured like this

```
app.set('views',  '/app/views');
```

And Jade is set as template engine:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
```

**Edit:**
In jade template:

```
ul
 each item in data
  li #{item.name}
```

Comment: ok now i added render but still its not showing up in the html page

Comment: Do you have 'views' directory configured in express.js?

Comment: Probably wrong file extension. Try to change extension to .jade or configure .html extension via app.set('view engine', 'html');

Comment: ok now i fixed the views but now i got these in the rendered jade file [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]

Comment: That is correct. You should change  li #{item} to whatever field you need to show, fx to li #{item.name}. Updated my answer.

Comment: great now i fixed, its  #{name.name} not #{name}  thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

First of all change your extension if you want node.js variable or object inside your html page then replace mongo.html extension to mongo.ejs

```
db.users.find({name:"raju",lastname:"david"},function(err,docs){if(docs)      {console.log(docs.name);}});    
     res.render(__dirname + '/mongo', {data: docs});
});
```

and inside mongo.html

```
<% data.forEach(function(dbData){ %>
          <%= dbData.name %>
          <%= dbData.lastName %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: what is data and dbData, please give example of some thing similar to the code i posted

Comment: if your query successfully executed then it will pass the object in docs.
then i assign this object to data or you can use any other name, it will take this object to the html page while rendering.
Then you can use this object in html page like the way I given in example !

Comment: yes its now working thanks but i like to use with jade.